# How Update MySQL Version in MAMP PRO v3.4

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mamp-pro

**MAMP PRO Mavens,**

It appears that (at least my instance of) MAMP PRO v3.4 installed and uses MySQL v5.5.42; although the version of MySQL (Community Server) is v5.7.9.

Would you be so kind as to explain the steps necessary to install and configure MySQL 5.7.9 to run in the MAMP PRO 3.4 environment (*e.g.,* work with MAMP PRO's installed Apache Server and PHP)?

Many, *many* thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I need to know how to do this too.

Comment: Updated to MAMP PRO v4.0.5, which now includes MySQL v5.6.28 (which solved originally posted problem).

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest version from http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php
2. Unpack the archive you just downloaded, the resulting folder should be called somewhat like "phpMyAdmin-x.y-all-languages"
3. Rename "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin" to "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin-OLD"
4. Copy "phpMyAdmin-x.y-all-languages" to "/Applications/MAMP/bin/"
5. Rename "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin-x.y-all-languages" to "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin"
6. Restart the MAMP and upgrading task is completed. You have successfully upgraded to latest phpMyAdmin or Mysql 4.2.10.1 version.